zsh, .bash_profile, and aliases
I have a script downloaded from the Internet, the beginning of which looks like this:
echo "alias myip='curl -s https://api.ipify.org/'" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "alias myiplookup='ip2cc \$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)'" >> ~/.bash_profile

I use it on a macOS machine and, as expected, it creates a .bash_profile file in my $HOME directory, with the corresponding lines:
alias myip='curl -s https://api.ipify.org/'
alias myiplookup='ip2cc $(curl -s https://api.ipify.org/)'

There are two bashes on that machine:

bash 3.2, supplied with the macOS itself
bash 5.2, installed using Homebrew

But regardless of which of these bashes I try, when I type myip or myiplookup, I get the command not found message.
Here is what I have tried, step by step:

Start the Terminal app. It will be opened with a zsh session.
Type bash (for bash 5.2) or /bin/bash (for bash 3.2)
Type myip. bash shows the command not found message.

What am I doing wrong?

Not sure if you want to, but you can make the bash installed via homebrew  the default login shell by issuing chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash.  You may also need to place /usr/local/bin/bash in /etc/shells

.bash_profile is only used when initialising login shells. If you want its contents to be interpreted, you need to add -l to your bash invocations.
Alias definitions typically go in .bashrc which is used for interactive shells. See Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?

The OP might have expected this to work (or perhaps followed a guide which expected it to work) because MacOS starts login shells by default (or used to, when it used bash, not sure what it does with zsh these days). See: Why are interactive shells on OSX login shells by default?
